# Avoid killing and restarting a Service when the screen rotates

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I'm developing an Android application using Services to perform asynchronous operations.

For now, I have been following the recommended pattern to unbind the service when the UI is closed

```
onStart(){
    context.bindService();
}

onResume(){
    serviceConnection.registerCallback(this); //register/unregisterCallback is defined in my domain
    checkServiceForPendingUIActionsToRequestUser();
}

onPause(){
    serviceConnection.unregisterCallback(this);
}

onStop(){
    context.unbindService();
}
```

The problems with this approach are two:

- When I rotate the device to test for different layout, a cycle of unbind/bind is correctly performed and ultimately I see the service resets itself to the original state
- The service is designed to post a notification if UI is not in display to draw the attention of the user to perform an action: when user taps the notification the UI is supposed to check the service state and require appropriate input (the long-named method), however I can see that the service gets reset again to its original state

It's not a good practice to comment out the `unbindService()` call to keep the service alive, but anyway I must keep my service (which also runs as foreground when not awaiting for input) alive at least until the screen rotation is done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1: Don't use the binding pattern, but rather the command pattern (`startService()` in conjunction with `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`).

Option #2. Bind on the `Application` context in a retained fragment, unbinding when the fragment itself is destroyed. A retained fragment lives across configuration changes. The `Application` context avoids one possible area of memory leaks related to retaining the binding across the configuration change.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Local) demonstrates Option #2. In my `DownloadFragment`, I bind to the service in `onAttach()`:

```
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity host) {
    super.onAttach(host);

    appContext=(Application)host.getApplicationContext();
    appContext.bindService(new Intent(getActivity(),
                                      DownloadService.class), this,
                            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }
```

(with the fragment itself also serving as the `ServiceConnection`)

and I unbind in `onDestroy()`:

```
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    appContext.unbindService(this);
    disconnect();

    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Comment: I'm unsure I can get a service connection (thus supplying commands to the service) without binding to it. The onDestroy idea looks great, I thought it was only called when running on the emulator but it looks like I confused with other documentation topic

Comment: @djechelon: Nothing can be *only* accomplished via binding. Anything that you can do with binding, you can do via the command pattern in conjunction with other things (e.g., an event bus instead of some sort of callback/listener pattern).